# Creating a matrix of canvases

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to create a matrix of canvases which each would be the size of the device-width and device-height. The idea is to have this matrix from where the view would move from canvas to canvas by pressing a button. So basically you would only see one canvas at a time, and others would locate up/down and left/right out of the screen.

I'm really new to javascript and webdesign so I'm not sure if the canvas element is the best way to do this at all. I don't have any code to show because I just started this project and wanted to ask first to get it right from the begining.

Is the approach of multiple canvases a good way to go or what would be better option and how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: That seems like an OK solution, however, it will require some JavaScript and CSS. Preferably you would ask this question a little bit later, when you run into problems. This question is quite vague :) Reference to [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, sure! So if this is a correct way to do this, then let me rephrase the question. How to create multiple canvases automatically? Or is it possible at all, or should I just create them manually, which is not really what I'd like to do as I'm not sure how many canvases I will end up needing.

Comment: See my answer below. I hope that will guide you towards a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a small start to get you started with how you can make canvas elements dynamically. You should look at W3 Schools for reference on how to edit DOM elements. [Create element in the DOM.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvasElements = [];
  var canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas1.id = "canvas1";
  canvasElements.push(canvas1);
}
```

**What you want in your solution**

1) Make a CSS class with full width and height of the page.

2) Add canvas elements dynamically to the page using JavaScript and DOM manipulation.

3) For each canvas, add it to the DOM, and do the logic you want with it (render elements and draw circles / images whatnot). This will require a lot of JavaScript, so I would suggest you start out simple with a single canvas.

I hope that gets you going.